# htaccess redirect after midnight

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect a HTTP request after midnight on a certain date, so how do I change this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*$
RewriteRule ^mypage/?$ http://mysite.com/my-other-page/ [R=302,L]
```

So that it only happens after 2012-07-12 00:00:01

Comment: if it's a one time thing - why not just log-in the machine and change the file manually (at midnight) ?

Comment: Would it not be easier to just schedule a cron job to swap the new .htaccess file in?

Comment: sorry! just edited question - happens anytime AFTER midnight on certain date

Comment: @alfasin - this is not a one time thing - it happens frequently and I'm often doing something else at midnight.

Comment: @RowlandShaw - I don't think so. I have to set up a cron job and duplicate a file. I'm just looking for a extra condition line in the access file.

Comment: In that case, @Rowland Shaw's answer is the perfect solution, just create two copies of the files and use a cron-job to swap between them.

Comment: Would this help: http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/time_hour-rewritecond-time.html

Comment: @MyStream I see we posted the same link! (+1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you do not wish to do this in the framework/script, look into TIME variables for mod_rewrite:

Overview:
http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/time_hour-rewritecond-time.html

Example:
http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/mod_rewrite-variables-cheatsheet.html#TIME

Comment: Dynamic pages - PHP. I use htaccess for short URLs. This situation happens regularly and I don't want to clutter my index page with PHP redirects. Would be simpler for me to keep all this stuff in the access file.

Comment: @Owen I think the solution lies in his link.

Comment: Yeah, then the "TIME" variables are the way to go, see this page for an example: http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/mod_rewrite-variables-cheatsheet.html#TIME

Answer (score 0):

You should manage this in the code using date functions:

PHP example:

```
if ($date < $somedate) {
    header('HTTP/1.1 302 Found');
    header('Location: http://www.example.com/error.php');
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Would rather keep my redirecting in one place - ie, the htaccess file.